# Firefox Add-on Extension: Homepage override unexpected behavior

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, manifest.json

This is part of my `manifest.json`:

```
...
 "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "index.html"
  },
 "chrome_settings_overrides" : {
  "homepage": "index.html"
} 
...
```

`index.html` is loaded fine on every new tab.
However new windows, and on startup, all I get is a blank page.

I tried manually just setting the homepage in preferences  as the URL for `index.html` as the extension itself for example:

`moz-extension://1232131-32132131-321312-321321-321321/index.html`

The behavior improves, but isn't perfect. When I do this, the new windows load `index.html` fine but on a fresh start up (from closed application) all I see is a blank page again?

Any ideas what's going wrong? This only happens in Firefox, OK on Tor Browser and Google Chrome.

Comment: Just FYI the extension URLs are unique on each device. So I'm hoping you meant you were just testing by setting the homepage URL manually.

Comment: Did you try ./index.html ?

Comment: @Smile4ever Yes, I don't believe that's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, this was happening due to the extension not loading in time during startup when a fresh window is loaded.

The way I first addressed this was in my `background.js` file:

```
function loadStart(){
    browser.tabs.update(
        {
            url: "index.html"
        }
    )
}

browser.runtime.onStartup.addListener(loadStart)
```

However, if the setting to always use private browsing is active, the code above will not do anything as `runtime.onStartup` does not fire if an incognito/ private browsing profile is loaded.

To counter this:

```
function pushStart(data) {
    if (data == null) {
        loadStart()
    }
    else {
        console.log("tab is well defined")
    }
}

var currentTab = browser.tabs.getCurrent()

currentTab.then((data)=>(pushStart(data)))
```

The new window on fresh start up is trying to load the page bundled in the extension, but trips up because the extension itself hasn't loaded and isn't available.
Hence the above code works around that case.

Comment: Also FYI this is a filed bug in Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1490260